# Код работает не так как мне надо

Tags: python

Это код для вывода цифры из числа. Он берёт цифры справа на лево, а мне надо наоборот!

```
n = int(input('Введите число: '))
m = int(input('Введите номер цифры: '))
k = 0
for k in range(1,m+1):
    pos1 = n%10 
    n = n//10   
print(pos1)
```

Comment: **вывода цифры из числа** это как?

Answer (score 2):

Если не усложнять задачу, т.е. не преобразовывать текст в число, а потом наоборот (поскольку `input()` всегда возвращает строку), то так:

```
n = input('Введите число: ')
m = int(input('Введите номер цифры: '))
print(n[m - 1] if 0 < m < len(n) else f'Цифры с номером {m} в числе {n} нет')
```

```
Введите число: 987654321
Введите номер цифры: 7
3
```

Если все-таки необходимо выделять цифры из числа, то можно так:

```
n = int(input('Введите число: '))
m = int(input('Введите номер цифры: '))
buf, x = [], n
while x > 0:
    buf.insert(0, x % 10)
    x //= 10
print(buf[m - 1] if 0 < m < len(buf) else f'Цифры с номером {m} в числе {n} нет')
```

Во втором случае вместо цикла можно было обойтись `str(n)`, но тогда это бы превратилось в `n = str(int(input('Введите число: ')))` и выглядело бы вообще странно.